# Loop through JQuery array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm creating a self updating match/fixture script, which return data from a JSON Script which automatically updates. However the JSON script include 3 arrays live, upcoming and recent. How can i loop through all of these arrays instead of just matches[0] which is live? i've tried using loop, but it cant loop through the functions?

```
var lastLoadedMatch = 0,
  ajaxInterval = 5000;

$(function() {
  getMatches();

});

function getMatches(lastId) {
  $.getJSON('data.json', function(resp) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(resp));
    var matches = [resp.live, resp.upcoming, resp.recent];



    if (lastId) {
      matches[0] = matches[0].filter(
        function(match) {
          return match.id > lastId;
        });
    }

    if (matches[0].length) {
      $.each(matches[0], function(_, match) {
        console.log([match.match_id,lastLoadedMatch ])
        if (match.match_id > lastLoadedMatch) {
          lastLoadedMatch = match.match_id
        }
        if ($.trim(match.game) == "lol") {
        $('#part-1').append(matchHtml(this))
        } else if ($.trim(match.game) == "counterstrike") {
           $('#part-2').append(matchHtml(this))
        } else if ($.trim(match.game) == "dota2") {
           $('#part-3').append(matchHtml(this))
        } else if ($.trim(match.game) == "hearthstone") {
           $('#part-4').append(matchHtml(this))
        }


      });

    }else{

    }

    setTimeout(function() {
        getMatches(lastLoadedMatch);
      }, ajaxInterval);




  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap your code in one more $.each that will iterate of your matches array:

```
var matches = [resp.live, resp.upcoming, resp.recent];

$.each(matches, function(_, match) {

    if (lastId) {
      match = match.filter(
        function(match) {
          return match.id > lastId;
        });
    }

    if (match.length) {
      $.each(match, function(_, match) {
         ...
```

or you can concatenate the arrays:

```
var matches = resp.live.concat(resp.upcoming, resp.recent);
```

Comment: Okay i've used the first method is there a way to inside the loop know whether it is upcoming, live or recent being looped?

Comment: @PeterPik you can check index from `$.each`

Comment: so like if ($.each.index == resp.upcoming) ?

Comment: @PeterPik `$.each(matches, fuction(i, match) { if (i == 1) { // upcoming`